# Backward join Doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

Suppose I have 2 entity. FirstEntity nothing know about the secondEntity.
Second entity has srcFisrt and dstFirst links to the first entity.
The question is: how I can write query in doctrine to join second from first entity?

For example:

```
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select(array('second', 'src_first', 'dst_first'))
        ->from('TestOrm:SecondEntity', 'second')
        ->innerJoin('second.srcFirst', 'src_first')
        ->innerJoin('second.dstFirst', 'src_first');
```

Work`s good, but how I can write something like this?:

```
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select(array('first'))
        ->from('TestOrm:FirstEntity', 'first');
    if($isDstSection) {
        $qb->innerJoin('TestOrm:SecondEntity', 'second', ON, second.dstFirst = first);
    } else {
        $qb->innerJoin('TestOrm:SecondEntity', 'second', ON, second.srcFirst = first);
    }
    $qb->andWhere('second.isVisibleForExample', '1');
```

I know, that doctrine can't return "second" entity with hydration, because firstEntity don`t have link to the secondEntity. I just need to filter firstEntity by second

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work:

```
if($isDstSection) {
    $qb->innerJoin('TestOrm:SecondEntity', 'second', Join::WITH, 'second.dstFirst = first');
} else {
    $qb->innerJoin('TestOrm:SecondEntity', 'second', Join::WITH, 'second.srcFirst = first');
}
$qb->andWhere('second.isVisibleForExample = :visibility')
   ->setParameter('visibility', 1);
```